# Visual Studio 2019 c++latest random_device uniform_int_distribution throws unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unhandled-exception, uniform-distribution

```
    random_device device;
    uniform_int_distribution<long> dist(-5, 5);
    vector<long> v;
    v.resize(20);
    generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&] { return dist(device); }); // <- Unhandled exception.
```

Exception details:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00AB3FDF in test.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.
```

It used to work but now fails after installing the latest Visual Studio 2019 update. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: does this also happen if you create a brand new project instead of using the existing one, before the update ?

Comment: What do you mean "before the update"?

Comment: with "before the update" I mean your existing project which worked before you updated VS. just try creating a brand new project on some other location and check if it works then. if you still wonder why, i can give you a tip: messy temporary .vs folder

Comment: Which version exactly are you talking about? 16.8.4 or one of the preview builds of 16.9? Does it repro in both Debug & Release? Does it repro for x86 and x64 native? Does it happen in a simple console app or only in the context of your other code? Are you using C++14, C++17, or C++latest mode?

Comment: I am using 16.8.4 and the title of the post tells I am using c++latest.

Comment: I use a new project and solution and it works find. I deleted the `.vs` folder content, restart VS2019 on the existing solution. Now the `.vs` folder contains `v16` folder and the exception persists.

Comment: What OS is used? It seems that project is configured to use disabled/unsupported ISA subset, which usually only an issue on Win7 - early Win8 unpatched for that compilers

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error on VS2019 under win10.

Normally this kind of issue comes due corrupt temporary files within .vs folder or corrupt project settings, in this case after the VS update.

What you can do is to create a fresh new project and compare/copy the setting files to the existing project (with eventually update the filepaths). Also removing .vs folder at the existing project could help.